# Primefaces CSS Header too big

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an primefaces page with facelets, everything works fine. At the `header.xhtml` the Code is:

```
    <div class="title ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="display: table;overflow: hidden;width:100%">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="apo48.png" />
        <font size="6">Usermanagement und Selfcare</font>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align:right;">
            <h:outputText value="Willkommen #{login.user}"/><br/>
            <h:commandLink action="#{login.logout}" value="Logout"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So also the header looks fine, but there is a vertical scroll bar under the header. It seems like the header is one or two px to big. But why is its this way and what can I do?

[image]

**EDIT**
Okay a complete example: I have the `layout.xhtml`

```
<ui:debug hotkey="x" rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage == 'Development'}" />
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" style="border: 0;">
        <ui:include src="../header/header.xhtml"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" style="border: 0;">
        <ui:include src="../menu/navigation.xhtml"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border: 0;">
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

With the CSS

```
    .ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 95% !important;
    }
    .ui-datatable tbody td.wrap {
    white-space: normal;
    }
    .unresizable {
    resize: none;
    }
```

In the north layoutunit is the code mentioned above.

Comment: Please visit [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section of **Stackoverflow** it will help SOusers as well you too.

Comment: When having trouble with HTML/CSS, please don't show the server side code responsible for generating the HTML/CSS output. Instead, show the generated HTML/CSS output itself. HTML/CSS users do not necessarily know anything about any server side code, such as JSF. They do not necessarily know that `<h:graphicImage>` generates a HTML `<img>` element. You will have more chance in getting valuable answers from HTML/CSS users if you get rid of JSF noise in the question and reframe the question to show HTML/CSS in (runnable) MCVE flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two unit that can be used to set the width and height relative to the viewport size (window size) vh and vw. For setting the height and width of header you can do this

```
.title{
  height: 20vh;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

This code will set height of .title to 20% of window height.
Or you can easy set

```
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

**See also:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: Yes this true for the height. But my problem is, that the width is not correct. I tried to set `.title{
  width: 90vh;
}` but this will be ignored.

Comment: okay thats it. Thank you so much in my case it is `.title{ width: 99.5vw !important; }` i dont know why it is such a creepy decimal number but it works this way!